# Solving set of equations with complex variables (looking for critical points)

Tags: equation-solving, calculus-and-analysis, complex

I need to solve (a more complicated version of) the following set of equations :

```
     D[Func[z1, z2, z3, z4],z1] = 0;
     D[Func[z1, z2, z3, z4],z2] = 0;
     D[Func[z1, z2, z3, z4],z3] = 0;
     D[Func[z1, z2, z3, z4],z4] = 0;
```

Where z1, z2, z3 and z4 are all complex. I need to solve for them. Here is what I am trying to do, But there are problems with dealing with the complex differentiation and Imaginary part etc.

```
    Func = Exp[Sum[If[
     i < j, (Log[
     EllipticTheta[1, Subscript[z, i] - Subscript[z, j], Subscript[z, 4]]]^2 -
      Im[Subscript[z, i] - Subscript[z, j]]^2/Im[Subscript[z, 4]]), 0], {i, 1, 
     3}, {j, 1, 3}]]

     NSolve[Table[D[Func, Subscript[z, i]], {i, 4}], Table[Subscript[z, i], 
      {i,4}]]
```

EDIT : Here I rephrase my question for clarity. I want to look for critical points of the following function in complex variables `z2, z3, z4` and `\tau` :

```
       f = Exp[Sum[
            If[i < j, (Log[
            EllipticTheta[1, 
            Subscript[z, i] - Subscript[z, j], \[Tau]]]^2 - ((Im[
            Subscript[z, i] - Subscript[z, j]])^2/Im[\[Tau]])), 
            0], {i, 2, 4}, {j, 2, 4}]]
```

Comment: Getting rid of subscripts by `Func = (Exp[       Sum[If[i <           j, (Log[EllipticTheta[1, Subscript[z, i] - Subscript[z, j],               Subscript[z, 4]]]^2 -            Im[Subscript[z, i] - Subscript[z, j]]^2/            Im[Subscript[z, 4]]), 0], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 3}]] /.       Table[Subscript[z, i] -> z[i], {i, 1, 4}]) /.     Table[Subscript[z, j] -> z[j], {j, 1, 4}];  NSolve[Table[D[Func, z,[i]], {i, 4}], Table[z[i], {i, 4}]]`, I obtain "NSolve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to NSolve.".

Comment: Wait, where are the equations `==`in your code...? Also, are you trying to find a critical point here? If yes and it is also an extremum, then use `FindMinimum/Maximum` instead.

Comment: @user64494 Yes. And it gives Im'[z4] etc. I need to solve them as complex variables. Tried explicitly defining as z = x + I y and also complex differntiation. But yet to get it work.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer Yes, I am looking for saddles. But `FindMinimum` didn't work. Probably it needs real input only..?

Comment: `FindInstance[Table[D[Func, z[i]] == 0, {i, 4}], Table[z[i], {i, 4}]]` fails too.

Comment: @user64494 Thanks! Yes, I tried that too. I have also rephrased my question for better clarity.

Comment: @PhysicsMoron:  `FindMinimum` won't work because the output of your function is complex-valued (I think.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Yes. Is there some way of finding critical points for this kind of problems with multiple complex variables?

Comment: Also, should `z1` appear in your definition of `f`?  It doesn't as it stands.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert No. That's just `\tau`. I copied it from my recent code..

Comment: My instinct is to try something with `FindRoot`, splitting the `z[i]` into their real & imaginary parts.  That makes it an 8-dimensional parameter space, though, and you'd only get a single numerical answer.  Maybe that's sufficient?

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Tried the 8 dim real problem too. But somehow didn't work. Actually my aim is to check the number of critical points it has.